# From a set of numbers {0,1,2,4,5,6} choose 5 of them, so that sum of the 5 numbers is divisible by 9

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> From a set of numbers {0,1,2,4,5,6} choose 5 of them,
>   so that sum of the 5 numbers is divisible by 9.

I solved it by grouping numbers in {1,2,6,0} and {5,4,0}, and observed that {1,2,4,5,6} works to fulfill the condition.

But, a confusion came to mind that if there is any other combination of 5 numbers with zero included. So, I started to make combinations using 0, which is not a good approach I believe. Can anyone clarify a concrete and easy way to deal this systematically even when these problems turn more difficult?

Comment: Since five of them is so close to being *all* of them, I would approach it by finding the total of all six numbers.  Then it will be clear which one to discard in order to have the remaining sum divisible by nine.

Comment: Did you forget to add $3$, or is it correct as is?

Comment: It was as it is given in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are six numbers.  They add up to 18.  To choose 5 of the numbers you must leave out one of them-- call it $a$.  So the sum of the five digits will be $18 - a$.  So we need $9|18-a $ which means $9|a $.  Of our 6 options $0$ is the only one divisible by $9$.  So our five numbers are all 6 except $0$.

If instead we need 5 numbers with the sum divisible by, say, $7$ we need $7|18-a $ so $7|4-a$.  Or $4-a \equiv 0 \mod 7$ or $a\equiv 4\mod 7$.  So $a =4$ and the 5 numbers are all of them except $4$.

Comment: Than you very much, that was just awsome :)